# Big 0 confusion: (log2(n))^x = O(n^y) where x>0,y>0 are constants

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

Why is n^y the upper bound of (log2(n))^x.My teacher took the values x=1000 and y =.1 for an example. But when i plotted then the graph for (log2(n))^x was always above n^y.If we take any value for n we can see that the value of     (log2(n))^x is always much greater than n^y especially when x is much bigger than y.

Comment: Even if `x = y`, _"`(log2(n))^x` was always above `n^y`"_ would be incorrect.

Comment: What if we take a very small value for y say y=.1 and a very very large value for x?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question.

Comment: I think asking about the theoretical performance for algorithms is very well related to computer programming.